# healthKit error in swift2 after migration from swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, healthkit

I had this code asking for write permissions working in `Swift 1.2` and after upgrading to `Swift 2.0` I getting a strange error:
`... '_' is not convertible to 'HKWorkoutType'`

code line where error appear:

```
let healthKitTypesToWrite = Set(arrayLiteral:[
        HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned),
        HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning),
        HKQuantityType.workoutType()
        ])
```

any ideas?

Comment: maybe consider upvoting if my answer was a time safer for you :)

Comment: I'm not allowed to up voting yet, as soon as I do, I will, thanks

Comment: done, btw: I have another question posted, with a strange error, maybe you  know the answer to that one also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `!` for first two items:

```
let healthKitTypesToWrite = Set(arrayLiteral:
[
    HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned)!, 
    HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning)!, 
    HKQuantityType.workoutType() 
])
```

This is required because `quantityTypeForIdentifier` returns `HKQuantityType?`